# problem with INIT=RUNSCRIPT and relative paths

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, configuration, h2

I use maven conventions for source paths (src/main src/test) and i have my sql scripts in src/main/resources/scripts.

I want to run my app with H2 memory and i'd like to use the jdbc url to initialize my db :

```
database.url=jdbc:h2:mem:;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'src/main/resources/scripts/create.sql';
```

My problem is that this relative path (src/main/... ) does not work, and that H2 won't crash if the init=runscript command targets nothing.

Does someone know what is the path i should use to make this work ?

Thanks

Comment: You wrote "H2 won't crash if the init=runscript command targets nothing" - I can't reproduce this (H2 throws an exception in this case). What version of H2 do you use? Could you try with the latest version? I'm not aware this was different before, but maybe it was.

Comment: No you're right, now it crashes. I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use the following url: 

`"jdbc:h2:mem:sample;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/create.sql'"`

With that one it is possible to run script from classpath. So you can just put it src/main/resources/scripts or src/test/resources/scripts in your maven (or something else) project.

Comment: I get `MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath` on Java 11

Comment: This does not work on H2 2.1.210 when using folders in path after `classpath:`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862699/problem-setting-up-h2-init-runscript-file-is-not-found-when-script-is-not-in-cl

Comment: Update to previous comment that it does not work: it does not work while using java modular system (module-info.java)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest trying to use an absolute path for starters, just to check everything works. Afterwards, check your classpath. For example, `bin/main/resources/scripts/create.sql`, assuming `bin` is where your classes are compiled, and is on your classpath.

Since `src`, where your source lives, usually isn't on the classpath, this could be the source of your problem.

Comment: With the absolute path, it works, but not any combination of relative paths i tried.

Comment: @Maxime: does H2 throw any error? Any sign of things not working from it's side mentioning that create.sql isn't found? Have you tried to put create.sql in the classpath?

Comment: sorry : With the absolute path, it works, but not any combination of relative paths i tried. The scripts are in mywar.war/WEB-INF/classes/scripts/.. I tried /WEB-INF/.. WEB-INF/.. etc no results :/

Comment: _Since `src`, where your source lives, usually isn't on the classpath_
In Maven projects Whatever is inside `src/main/resources` usually **is** included in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

For me it works if I keep the scripts under `src/test/resources`:

```
database.url=jdbc:h2:mem:;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'src/test/resources/create.sql';
```

Anyway, in a JUnit context, if you use the conventional file paths `schema.sql` (for the DDL) and `data.sql` (for the DDL) under `src/test/resources`, you don't need the specify the scripts with the INIT variable in the connection string.
You can simply use:

```
database.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

and JUnit will automatically run the scripts when creating the H2 instance in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are specifying `'src/`
You need to do `./src` instead.

I had the same issue and this change fixed it:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./src/main/resources/data.sql;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM './src/main/resources/data.sql'
```

If you are using Docker and Kubernetes,

**add** this line to Dockerfile

```
COPY src/main/resources/data.sql /app/src/main/resources/
```