# How to populate H2 in-memory DB from a file (populate.sql)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I want to add H2 in-memory db to my Spring MVC application. For ORM I’m using Hibernate. Here is my configs:

[hibernate.cfg.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/myDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">qwerty</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="de.alf.h2.entity.Student"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[data.xml]

```
<bean:beans xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="de.alf.h2.repository"/>
    <bean:bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <bean:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean:bean>
    <bean:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <bean:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean:bean>
    <bean:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <bean:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean:bean>
</bean:beans>
```

[web.xml]

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/data.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I need to create db from a file (resource/db/data.sql).

```
CREATE TABLE student {
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR (250)
}
```

How to do this in my code?

Comment: Do you need to populate a db or to create a db?

Comment: I need to populate db.

Answer (score 6):

If `hbm2ddl.auto` is set to `create`, `Hibernate` will generate DDL from mapped classes during the `SessionFactory` creation. You can also add a file named `import.sql` to your classpath to import some data.

If you are using M2 for testing purpose and you want to do it by yourself, you can also use the `H2` [Execute SQL on Connection](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection) feature :

```
jdbc:h2:~/myDB;INIT=runscript from '~/resource/db/data.sql'
```

** Note that the path to `data.sql` might be differents.

Comment: I'm getting an exception now `Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-176]`

Comment: It seem that the database was already running or something. try to kill the process.

Comment: I killed it. Now OK. But where I should add `jdbc:h2:~/myDB;INIT=runscript from '~/resource/db/data.sql'`? To `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/myDB;INIT=runscript from '~/resource/db/data.sql'</property>

Comment: It didn't work. When my app has been started it hasn't any populated data.

Comment: Even if I'm using `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/myDB;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/h2/populate.sql'</property>`

Comment: Are you sure that the path is OK?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490138/problem-with-init-runscript-and-relative-paths

Answer (score 4):

you can use JDBC namespace `xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"` then you can add embedded database as

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

then use this data source in JDBCTemplate or in JPA with hibernate