# How to load sql script file using INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'mytestscript.sql' and check it's loaded or not

Tags: database, junit, h2

I am trying to execute some sql script using

property name="url" value="someurl;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'mytestscript.sql';

I am not sure -

1. Sql script file loaded or not, Since these configuration has been done for Junit using H2 database i can't run query to verify the same in database

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that connection URL is used by your test system as is and the same database is not already open without such `INIT` parameter, you can be sure that script will be executed completely without any errors, H2 does not open a connection if `INIT` wasn't completed normally, an `SQLException` will be thrown on connection attempt.

Comment: Thanks @Evgenij. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490138/problem-with-init-runscript-and-relative-paths worked for me. I had my script in different directory than resources.